# Valgrind, Open file descriptors at exit

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm coding a program in which a parent is executing function and needs to write the results of these function to a pipe. The child has to read the pipe and put everything in a logging file. I forked the parent (which uses the function fifomanager_write(), see below) and the child uses the function fifomanager_write() (see below). I opened a fifo using mkfifo (using FIFO_NAME).  I close the fifo file everytime I exit the function  but valgrind still mentiones that there are file desriptors open after exiting the programme (see below). Can somebody explain based on my code if I'm missing something?

```
void fifomanager_read()
{
  int sequencenumber = 1;
  char recv_buf[MAX];
  FILE*fp;
  fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "r"); 
  CHECK_FIFOOPEN(fp);
  
  FILE*logfile;
  logfile = fopen(FIFO_LOG, "a"); 
  CHECK_FIFOOPEN(logfile);
  fprintf(logfile, "start of new log\n");
  do  
  {
    fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "r");
    CHECK_FIFOOPEN(fp);
    if ( fgets(recv_buf, MAX, fp) != NULL )
    { 
      #ifdef DEBUG
      printf("Message received: %s", recv_buf);
      #endif
      //print to log file
      fprintf(logfile,"%d %ld %s",sequencenumber, time(NULL), recv_buf);
      sequencenumber++; 
    }
  } while(strcmp(recv_buf, "End of logging process\n")!=0); 
  int result = fclose( logfile );
  CHECK_FIFOCLOSED(result);

  result = fclose( fp );
  CHECK_FIFOCLOSED(result);
  #ifdef DEBUG
  printf("both files closed \n");
  #endif
}

void fifomanager_write(char*recv_buf)
{
  FILE*fp;
  fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "w");
  CHECK_FIFOOPEN(fp);
  //put a lock as you are putting values in the fifo
  pthread_mutex_lock(&fifolock);
  if ( fputs( recv_buf, fp ) == EOF ) 
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Error writing data to fifo\n");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  FFLUSH_ERROR(fflush(fp)); 
  
  #ifdef DEBUG
  printf("Message send: %s", recv_buf);
  #endif
  //close fifo
  int result = fclose(fp);
  CHECK_FIFOCLOSED(result);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&fifolock);
}
```

************* RESULT ************

```
FILE DESCRIPTORS: 13 open at exit.
==3503== Open file descriptor 13: MYFIFO
==3503==    at 0x4AC5EAB: open (open64.c:48)
==3503==    by 0x4A48195: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:189)
==3503==    by 0x4A48459: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:281)
==3503==    by 0x4A3AB0D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:75)
==3503==    by 0x4A3AB0D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==3503==    by 0x10AF08: fifomanager_read (in /home/rikvandevelde/labfinal/Lab8/sensor_gateway)
==3503==    by 0x10AADB: run_child (in /home/rikvandevelde/labfinal/Lab8/sensor_gateway)
==3503==    by 0x10AA87: main (in /home/rikvandevelde/labfinal/Lab8/sensor_gateway)
==3503== 
==3503== Open file descriptor 12: MYFIFO
==3503==    at 0x4AC5EAB: open (open64.c:48)
==3503==    by 0x4A48195: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:189)
==3503==    by 0x4A48459: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:281)
==3503==    by 0x4A3AB0D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:75)
==3503==    by 0x4A3AB0D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==3503==    by 0x10AF08: fifomanager_read (in /home/rikvandevelde/labfinal/Lab8/sensor_gateway)
==3503==    by 0x10AADB: run_child (in /home/rikvandevelde/labfinal/Lab8/sensor_gateway)
==3503==    by 0x10AA87: main (in /home/rikvandevelde/labfinal/Lab8/sensor_gateway)
```

Comment: You do open the same file multiple times (you open it before the loop and than every time the loop iterates), and you only close it once, after the loop. I would assume the second open inside the loop is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

```
fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "r");
...
do
{
    fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "r");
    ...
} while (strcmp(recv_buf, "End of logging process\n") != 0);
...

result = fclose(fp);
```

You are not closing the `fp`s you `fopen` throughout your `do-while` loop - only the last one - and you are overriding the first `fp` you opened.

---

For future reference: when compiling with `-g`, valgrind can output very useful debugging information - such as a stacktrace with line numbers that can show where leaked memory was allocated. This can help you find the source of memory leaks very quickly.

Comment: Big thanks for your comment! I'll have a look at it.